# Vue - Passing props to computed

Tags: vue.js

I have the following setup:

```
//someFile.Vue
<template>
 <ABC foo="myPath"/>
<template>
<script>
  import ABC from 'somewhere';
  export default {
    components: { ABC },
  }
</script>
```

```
// ABC.vue
<template>someData...</template>
<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  export default {
    props: ['foo'],
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        myTest: this.foo+"/someVuexAction',
      }),
    }
  }
</script>
```

However, I consistently get the message 'Cannot read property foo of undefined.  I thought computed values could read props.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Access one of your vuex store methods by building its name from the props ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access one of your vuex getter depending on the `foo` prop value. The problem is the first time your computed method is evaluated `this` (the instance of your component) does not exist yet. I'm not sure if mapGetters can handle being dynamically re-evaluated once `this` exist (I don't think so). You can try this (**edit: does not work, see second solution**) :

```
...mapGetters({
    myTest: this && this.foo ? this.foo+'/someVuexAction' : undefined
})
```

It probably won't work, but it's worth trying.

**Second solution**, more likely to work, is to define your computed property as follow :

```
computed: {
  myVuexGetter() {
    return this.foo ? this.$store.getters[this.foo+'/someVuexGetter'] : undefined
  },
}
```

**Side note** : you used the terminology `someVuexAction` but you called it inside `mapGetters`. If it is not a typo : you should use `mapActions` to import vuex actions, and actions are not computed properties, they are methods.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. Yes, that was a typo about getter/action.  I will test it out and report back

Comment: Converting my code to use the myVuexGetter() example you showed did the trick! Many thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for reporting, i will edit my answer to reflect the fact that the first solution does not work !

Answer (score 0):

But [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) is going to map to a store's functions.  The store doesn't have a `foo`, your component does.  I think you just want to put a regular function on the computed, not a mapped one.

Consider the example below:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 5
  },
  getters: {
    counterCount: state => {
      return state.counter;
    }
  }
});

const {
  mapGetters
} = Vuex;

Vue.component("my-el", {
  props: {
    foo: Number
  },
  template: "<div>foo: {{foo}} | fooPlusOne: {{fooPlusOne}} | myTest: {{myTest}}</div>",
  computed: {
    fooPlusOne: function() {
      return this.foo + 1;
    },
    ...mapGetters({
      myTest: "counterCount"
    })
  }
});

const vm = new Vue({
  store,
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-el :foo="8"></my-el>
</div>
```